# Neighbourhood points (2d)

Tags: algorithms, geometry

I have a 2d coordinates system with some points on it, like this one:

[image: coordinate system with some points on it]

Now I am looking for an algorithm (or just some approach) to find neighboured points.
So, if you have the coordinates of one point, and a list of other ones, how to find all neighbours of that point?  I really have no idea how to do this.

If I look at the orange point, the grey, the blue and the light green one are obviously neighbours of it, but what about the others?

You could put circles around the points... and look if any other of the points is in this circle. Those points should be listed as being neigbours of the first point.

**What I had:** An array with tuples in it, every tuple representing the (x,y)-coodrinates of a point.

**What I wanted:** A dictionary/map: the *keys* are every tuple from the above list and the value of such a point-tuple should be a list out of all it's neighbours.

**Problems:**

- How do I define what is a *neighbourhood* of two points? What would the inputs be to such a definition (e.g. proximity threshold)?
- What would be a strategy to design and implement this?

Comment: This is just variation on the [closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) and the [nearest neighbor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).  Have you read those Wikipedia pages and looked at their algorithms?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: @MichaelT Since I want _all_ neighbours of _any_ point in the space and not just the two ones that are nearest to each other, I don't know to make this variation. No, I have not read through these articles, I will do now.

Comment: @palsch Depending on the algorithm used, you eliminate the one you find from the set and repeat until the nearest neighbor is greater than some threshold.  You might even be able to reuse some of the data previously calculated. There are lots ways to tweak the algorithms presented to give you the data you are after.

Comment: @MichaelT How to find that threshold?

Comment: That is the problem you need to solve. You describe the blue and light green ones as "obviously neighbors" - but what do *you* mean by that. You appear to have some threshold that you are using.

Comment: How do you define what is or is not a neighbour?

Comment: @Jules That's the big part of the question.

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah, but apparently that was my brain setting the threshold... and my programming language has no brain, so it's difficult to program that. :(

Comment: That is the essence of programming - transforming thought to code. You need to identify the heuristics you are using to identify neighborhoods of points.

Comment: A query that would return a set of nearby points would be called *multidimensional range search* query. Multidimensional can refer to 2D, 3D and up. Even 2D is non-trivial; you cannot implement the 2D search on linear data structures. Also read about kD-tree, R-tree, quadtree, and Morton-code (Z-order curve; related to quadtree).

Comment: @MichaelT Okay, let me try... I chose those ones because... the largest distance from the orange one to each of them is about less than half the distance of the distance orange-brown or orange-pink or orange-darkgreen. Maybe I could use _that_.

Comment: Multi-dimensional range search queries are performed progressively, a bit like search results are ranked and then returned in "pages". Within each "batch" of results, hits are sorted by distance (which can be L1, L2, or some other distance measure). The first batch of hits will be ...

Comment: The first batch of results will be performed with a distance (range) of R1. After the query submitter has finished checking all results within R1, if it wants more results, it will increase the distance (range) to R2, and so on, until it is satisfied or decides to cancel the search.

Comment: @palsch and now you're looking at something that sounds like charting all of the points as a function of distance to orange and taking those that fall within the nth percentile or mth standard deviation. But what works for you is something that needs to be discovered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to define "neighboring points" as points that share an edge with area of point in [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

To calculate which points are "neighbors" in voronoi diagram, you use [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

Comment: That's a rather reasonable definition (and possibly a neat codegolf challenge). As an example, could you show the image this would result in as a visual aid?

Comment: **1)** I like Voronoi diagrams. :) **2)** I will accept your answer as soon as I have "translated" it into code. **3)** Thanks!